# Issue adding and printing elements of a List managed by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I've got an issue right here, I'm getting a memory violation error (I am handling the memory) and also a wrong input. What I am doing is a pointer managed list.

My code is supposed to do: Update the referenced pointer with multiple entries and print them. It does it partially, let me show you.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Lyric
{
    Lyric* next;
    tuple<int, string> tuple;
};

void Addition(Lyric*& poetry, tuple<int, string> tpl)
{
    Lyric* newl = new Lyric;
    newl->tuple = tpl;
    newl->next = poetry;
    poetry = newl;
}
void PrintScr(Lyric*& poetry)
{
    if (poetry == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty list !" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Lyric* prel = poetry;
        while (prel != NULL)
        {
            cout << "Printing the integer: " << get<0>(prel->tuple) << endl;
            cout << "Printing the string : " << get<1>(prel->tuple) << endl;
            cout << "------------------------------------------" << endl;
            prel = prel->next;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    string a_str[] = {"test1", "test2"};
    Lyric* poetry = new Lyric();
    /*
    int size = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    Addition(poetry, i, make_tuple(i, a_str[i]));
    */
    Addition(poetry, make_tuple(0, a_str[0]));
    Addition(poetry, make_tuple(1, a_str[1]));
    PrintScr(poetry);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Output:

[image: Error]

So it's supposed to print them in the order they've been added . My best bet is that I've screwed something up in the PrintScr method because it prints them in reverse and also prints a non-existing item, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am going through the elements one by one and printing them....

This is how it's supposed to look like :

```
Printing the integer : 1
Printing the string  : test1
-------------------------------
Printing the integer : 2
Printing the string  : test2
-------------------------------
```

Comment: As soon you have members which are pointers delete the default copy constructors/assignment operators (C++11) or make them private (I am just paranoid here). After that think about proper copy construction/assignment. Also, do not forget proper destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
Lyric* poetry = new Lyric();
```

The default constructor of `Lyric` does not set a sane value to the `next_` member. It remains uninitialized and you get undefined behavior when you dereference it.

What you need is:

```
Lyric* poetry = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never initializing the next ptr in Lyric to NULL, so when you get to the last item in the list it's some garbage pointer that causes a crash when you try to access the memory it's pointing to.

You can fix this by setting next to NULL in Lyric's constructor or just setting poetry->next = NULL in main.cpp right after you create it.

I should also point our that you're inserting at the front of the list instead of the back of the list inside Addition() which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also thanks for pointing out the issue with the way the items were added.

Comment: Also, the other poster's example will work better than my answer because my answer will also require you to initialize poetry->tuple to the first tuple you want to use.  His version is probably the better quick fix for your code.  But you should really look into improving your linked list implementation (or, better, just use an std::dequeue or some other container)